# How could i use this SQL on cypher(neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

hi how can i transform this SQL Query as CYPHER Query ? :

```
SELECT n.enginetype, n.Rocket20, n.Yearlong, n.DistanceOn,
FROM TIMETAB AS n
JOIN PLANEAIR AS p ON (n.tailnum = p.tailNum)
```

If it is requisition before using that query to create any relationship or antyhing please write and help with that one too.. thanks

Comment: Try read answers like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005125/how-to-translate-sql-queries-to-cypher-in-the-optimal-way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005125/how-to-translate-sql-queries-to-cypher-in-the-optimal-way)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good [guide for comparing SQL with Cypher](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sql-to-cypher/) and showing the equivalent Cypher for some SQL queries.

If we were to translate this directly, we'd use :PLANEAIR and :TIMETAB node labels (though I'd recommend using better names for these), and we'll need a relationship between them. Let's call it :RELATION.

Joins in SQL tend to be replaced with relationships between nodes, so we'll need to create these patterns in your graph:

```
(:PLANEAIR)-[:RELATION]->(:TIMETAB)
```

There are several ways to get your data into the graph, usually through [LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/). The general approach is to MERGE your :PLANEAIR and :TIMETAB nodes with some id or unique property (maybe TailNum?, use `ON CREATE SET ...` after the MERGE to add the rest of the properties to the node when it's created, and then MERGE the relationship between the nodes.

The [MERGE section](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) of the developers manual should be helpful here, though I'd recommend reading through the entire dev manual anyway.

With this in place, the Cypher equivalent query is:

```
MATCH (p:PLANEAIR)-[:RELATION]->(n:TIMETAB)
RETURN n.Rocket20,p.enginetype, n.year, n.distance
```

Now this is just a literal translation of your SQL query. You may want to reconsider your model, however, as I'm not sure how much value there is in keeping time-related data for a plane separate from its node. You may just want to have all of the :TIMETAB properties on the :PLANEAIR node and do away with the :TIMETAB nodes completely. Of course your queries and use cases should guide how to model that data best.

EDIT

As far as creating the relationship between :PLANEAIR and :TIMETAB nodes (and again, I recommend using better labels for these, and maybe even keeping all time-related properties on a :Plane node instead of a separate one), provided you already have those nodes created, you'll need to do a joining match, but it will help to have a unique constraints on :PLANEAIR(tailnum) :TIMETAB(tailNum) (or an index, if this isn't supposed to be a unique property):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:PLANEAIR)
ASSERT p.tailNum IS UNIQUE

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:TIMETAB)
ASSERT n.TailNum IS UNIQUE
```

Now we're ready to create the relationships

```
MATCH (p:PLANEAIR)
MATCH (n:TIMETAB)
WHERE p.tailNum = n.tailNum
CREATE (p)-[:RELATION]->(n)
REMOVE n.tailNum
```

Now that the relationships are created, and :TIMETAB tailNum property removed, we can drop the unique constraint on :TIMETAB(tailNum), since the relationship to :PLANEAIR is all we need.

```
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (n:TIMETAB)
ASSERT n.tailNum IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific and walk me through how can i create that relationship, i dont need a LOAD CSV tutorial because i have already done that, i just need somehow to link PLANE1 to TIME1 with the artribute TailNum how can i do that so that your Cypher query would work ?

Comment: Edited to include relationship creation. I'd recommend reading through the developer's guide and going through some of the Cypher tutorials in the Neo4j browser.

Comment: @Serenade I accepted your edits for now (made a few fixes), but please, don't edit other's answers like this for this reason. If you're going to change your labels in your own code, that's fine, but there's no need to change them in your question and edit others' answers to comply with the change.